# Mpdf php mysql select limit records

Tags: php, select, mpdf

Selecting records from database:

```
$dados = mysql_query($query_dados, $valesilveira) or die(mysql_error());
# $totalRows_dados = mysql_num_rows($dados); # you don't need this unless you're using
                                   # $totalRows_dados somewhere else

# check for number of results. If there are none, exit / die / return / whatever
if (mysql_num_rows($dados) == 0) {
echo "no results found!";
# die / exit / return false / etc.
}

# initialise a string to hold the articles
$articles = '';

# loop through the results one at a time
while ($row_dados = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados)) {
# append the article div on to our existing string
$articles .= '

<div id="articles">
<div class="titulobold"><p>&nbsp;'.$row_dados['titulo'].'</p></div>
<div class="wid10"><p>'.$row_dados['posicao'].'</p></div>
<div class="wid15"><p><img src="images/artigos/'.$row_dados['folder'].'/'.$row_dados['id_artigo'].'.png" style="height:60px;" /></p></div>
<div class="wid30"><p>&nbsp;'.$row_dados['desc'].'</p></div>
<div class="wid15"><p>'. number_format( $row_dados['unitario'], 2 ) .'€</p></div>
<div class="wid15"><p>'. number_format( $row_dados['unitario']*$row_dados['quantidade'], 2 ) .'€</p></div>
<div class="wid10"><p>'.$row_dados['quantidade'].'</p></div>
</div>

';

// any other stuff you want to do to each piece of row data can go here

}
```

But for some reason is not work like i want because in each page the records start going up, ill expain with images for more info:

```
http://i.imgur.com/TEv0GNj.jpg - Page 1
http://i.imgur.com/8Z1WBqR.jpg - Page 2
http://i.imgur.com/iMtX4fU.jpg - Page 3
```

And it keep going upper its like a loop.

Please tell me what to do.

The rest of the code:

```
//==============================================================
//==============================================================
//==============================================================

include("mpdf.php");

$mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','','',15,15,139,28,9,9); 

$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($header);
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer);

// LOAD a stylesheet
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('css/print.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);    // The parameter 1 tells that this is css/style only and no body/html/text

$mpdf->WriteHTML($articles);

$mpdf->Output();

exit;
//==============================================================
//==============================================================
//==============================================================
```

Comment: Well, it does not seem like a php/mysql error. It's rather like something is messed up with html/css. Would you mind sharing the contents of $header, $footer and css/print.css?

Comment: not at all, the code as been added.

Comment: ok just fixed puting: style="height:94px;" on the artigos div :)